# JSON parse not getting value from array

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

I'm executing a JSON parse on an array returned from a PHP function and it doesn't seem to be working.

Here's the PHP function:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<?php

   $bname = $_REQUEST["bname"];

         $link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '123'); 

   $servername = "localhost";
   $username = "root";
   $password = "123";
   $dbname = "success";

   // Create connection
   $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
   // Check connection
   if ($conn->connect_error) {
       die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
   }
   // PHP for execution
   $sql = "SELECT id, bname, bicon, rafrica, rasia, roceania, reurope, rsouthamerica, rnorthamerica, traffic, revenue, profit FROM business LIMIT 1";
   $result = $conn->query($sql);

   if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
       // output data of each row
       while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
           $b3name = $row["bname"]. "<br>";
           $b3icon = $row["bicon"]. "";
           $b3rafrica = $row["rafrica"]. "<br>";
           $b3rasia = $row["rasia"]. "<br>";
           $b3roceania = $row["roceania"]. "<br>";
           $b3reurope = $row["reurope"]. "<br>";
           $b3rsouthamerica = $row["rsouthamerica"]. "<br>";
           $b3rnorthamerica = $row["rnorthamerica"]. "<br>";
           $b3traffic = $row["traffic"]. "<br>";
           $b3revenue = $row["revenue"]. "<br>";
           $b3profit = $row["profit"]. "<br>";
       }
   } else {
       echo "0 results";
   }

   $output = array(
       'name' => $b3name,
       'icon' => $b3icon,
       'traffic' => $b3traffic
   );
   
   echo json_encode($output);

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the AJAX that contains the JSON parse:

```html
  function loadfacebook1()
  {
   var xmlhttp;
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
     {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
     xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
     }
   else
     {// code for IE6, IE5
     xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
     }

   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
     {
     if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
       {
       document.getElementById("b1").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
       }
     } 
    
    xmlhttp.open("GET","getfacebook.php",true);
   xmlhttp.send();

   var obj = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=obj.name + "<br>";
  }
```

I'm using

```html
<span id="demo">
```

to display the returned value but I need to assign obj.name (and some other elements of the array) to a variable(s) which I can use to update other things in the page. Any help would be really appreciated.

Cheers,

Will

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move the parsing of received JSON into the function called when the AJAX response is delivered (onreadystatechange)

Comment: Did you mean like this?


   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
     {
     if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
       {
       document.getElementById("b1").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
       var obj = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=obj.name;
       }
     }

Comment: Sorry for the formatting, It's the first time I've pasted code in to a comment and it doesn't mini-Markdown formatting doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Don't worry I had the same problems :) So yes something like that. Did it help you?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I think it should be working but it still isn't? I think perhaps I might be doing something else wrong too. I am terrible at this! I wish I could live in Photoshop not Sublime! If you can see anything else that's very wrong please let me know. I'm trying to get multiple values from the array that the PHP function is returning so that I can change a few different things on the page using an onclick event (and AJAX as seen above). Thanks again

Comment: So what is your current output and the expected one? I mean what do you get from the ajax call? (You can see it in your browser's tools). I see that your php script is returning only the info from the last row fetched from db. Does your new problem is connected with the parsed data?

Comment: Basically I'm trying to fetch the first row of a table called business on a MySQL database (success). I'm using the PHP to grab every value in the row and return it in an array (so that I can return multiple values). Then I'm using the JSON parse in the AJAX to break down the array that has been returned from the PHP so that I can use each value individually. I'm not sure where it's going wrong - at the moment the <span id="demo></span> is not displaying anything when I click. If I remove the array and JSON parse I can return a single value. So I think the problem is the array/parse.

Comment: my bad I didn't see the limit at the end (while loop confused me)... ok it is weird that it doesn't work by you. I tried to recreate your case and works by me. Can you see in your browser's tools (in network traffic) what data does your call give you back? Or maybe if you get anny errors from JS (see in the console)? Btw. close the <span> block :)

Comment: No problem - I should have mentioned it in my original post. Could you show me the version that you have recreated? That may help. I've used the browser tools and it isn't displaying any errors. I don't know how to view network traffic in firebug so I can't see what the call back is returning. How do I do that? And I had already closed the <span> block, I just didn't include it in the original post, sorry! Thanks again

Comment: Before I will send it to you tell me if you followed the tip which @Jake gave you? you should delete the html code from your php script. Remember that the json data has nothing to do with html tags and does not need to be surrounded by it. I guess this may cause the problem by you right now.

Comment: I changed the PHP script (remove the HTML tags). Now when I click the button with Firebug open I get the following error: "TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null
 

document.getElementById("b1").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;"

Comment: do you have any element with id "b1"? It looks like it cannot find it in your DOM structure.

Comment: I'm confused because I wrote this a while ago. Where is it looking for this element from? Does b1 refer to something on the database?

Comment: I got it to work! Turns out I didn't need that line at all. I think the JSON array was meant to replace a line that I had written previously. That's what was causing the problem. Now my only other question is how would I get other elements of the array? Do I simply copy and paste that code for the other parts of the array. I.e.        var obj = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
    document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML=obj.icon;

Comment: It depends what exactly do you want to do with this other data. Can you describe what do you want to have?

Comment: I'm using the data to change the style of a group of SVG paths. The app compares the data between two companies and displays it on a map which is an SVG. At the moment I'm doing it on load with PHP like this:    if ($b1rnorthamerica >= $b2rnorthamerica) {
       $northamericastyle ="b1";
   } else {
       $northamericastyle ="b2";
   }

   $conn->close();
but I now need to change the variables depending on the data that is pulled from the array. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: If I understood it corrctly you need to change some styles depending on the received data from your ajax call? So which data from received JSON says which element should be changed and which style applied?

Comment: Correct. The data received from JSON traffic is the number that needs to be compared against the other (already selected) business's traffic using an if statement. The styles are called b1 and b2. At the moment I'm using the variable $northamericastyle to change the style id to either b1 or b2.

Comment: Yes till now you use this variable but on the PHP side so you need to shift it into the client side (JS). It will be harder to solve it via the comments :) What is your starting style and traffic value?

Comment: So basically for each region on the map I run this if statement and it compares the revenue of business 1 to the revenue of business 2 in that specific region. Then it applies either b1 or b2 as a style:    if ($b1rafrica >= $b2rafrica) {

       $africastyle ="b1";
   } else {
       $africastyle ="b2";
   }

In this case b1rafrica is is 200 and b2rafrica is 150 so style b1 is applied. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes it makes sence :) I can help you further but will be much much faster if I will see the code or something I could analize and then give you an idea :) If you want send me email on public.inbox.00@gmail.com.

Answer (score 0):

When you are providing JSON results from PHP, you should exclude the HTML code. Try removing the following and see if it helps:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
```

and

```
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! That seemed to help something.